# Motion data tag only for X, Y and Z

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to change the motion for a only one direction?

I tried for example: `Motion[0:1d,1:~,2:,~]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to add more details to this question.  For starters, show us the full command you're trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

In Minecraft 1.14 and later versions, this can be done using the [`/data modify`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351499/185203) command:

To set the X coordinate of an entity:

```
/data modify entity <entity> Motion[<coord>] set value <value>d
```

Use `Motion[0]` for the X coordinate, `Motion[1]` for the Y coordinate, and `Motion[2]` for the Z coordinate.

Comment: I might be wrong, but don't indexes normally start at 0? Or is NBT different? Just checkin

Comment: Yes, they do. Oops.

Answer (score -1):

No, you must specify the 3 directions, and cannot use ~ in NBT.

So you cannot do so.

Comment: ty ! i found another way to do it