# Store an item in storage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have figured out how to place a selected item in a chest:

```
/data modify block -255 71 97 Items[{Slot:0b}] set from entity @p SelectedItem
```

How do I place a selected item in a storage using **/data modify storage ...** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy item NBT into an item entity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354964/how-to-copy-item-nbt-into-an-item-entity)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by storage? Storage is not for chests and item containers. The command you have provided is completely different.