# Data merge question

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an armorstand have the same rotation as the player. I've done this with storing the data Rotation[0], but you should be able to do it with data merge right?

I tried `/data modify entity @e[tag=Armorstand,limit=1] {} merge from entity @p Rotation[0]` but it doesn't work. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I couldn't get any info on the minecraft wiki about sourcepaths. I'm assuming the sourcepath is different from the one you use when using `data get` since `/data modify entity @e[tag=Armorstand,limit=1] {} merge from entity @p Rotation[0]` works if I remove "Rotation[0]", but then the armorstand gets all the data from the player and I only want the rotation.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Actual question, not auto-generated comment: Does this answer your question? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351499/171580 Basically you need the full path on both ends.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you! I was just waiting for you to answer. Turns out I was suprisingly close when I played around with it `/data modify entity @e[tag=Armorstand,limit=1] Rotation[0] set from entity @p Rotation[0]` 

I tried using Rotation[0] on both, but only with merge and not with set.

Comment: Duplicate of [Would someone give a thorough explanation of 1.14 Minecraft's /data modify?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351488/would-someone-give-a-thorough-explanation-of-1-14-minecrafts-data-modify)