# Modify Wandering Trader Trades

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need some help.

I don't fully understand `/data modify` yet, but I am learning. In the meantime, I would like to modify the data of every Wandering Trader that has the **x3 Emeralds > x3 Podzol** trade to be a trade for **x5 Emeralds > x1 Grass**, I want to change **ONLY THAT TRADE**, I would like the rest of the trades that the Trader spawned with to remain the same.

Here's what I have:

`/execute as @e[type=wandering_trader,nbt={Offers:{Recipes:[{sell:{id:"minecraft:podzol"}}]}}] run data modify entity @s ...`

and here's the data that I want to replace the podzol trade with:

`{maxUses:1,buyB:{id:"minecraft:air",Count:1b},buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:5},sell:{id:"minecraft:grass",Count:1b},xp:1,uses:0,priceMultiplier:0.05f,specialPrice:0,demand:0,rewardExp:1b}`

and that's where my knowledge of `modify` is exhausted, I have tried many different commands to no avail. I'm pretty sure that I need to use `/data modify ... set` but I don't know how to...

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does this help? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351499/171580 (actual question, not auto-text)

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes! Hours of research paid off, thank you so much.