# Minecraft 1.15 data command to edit entities

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have looked everywhere are the wiki is unusually hapless in this regard. I am trying to edit the data of a naturally-generated entity, for this example i will use a zombie.

```
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:iron_axe},{Count:1,id:iron_axe}],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:iron_helmet}],HandDropChances:[0.0f,0.0f],ArmorDropChances:[0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f]}
```

This command is simple enough to understand, but let's say I want all of the equipped items to be guaranteed drops (I instead want the items to drop upon the use of a specific item, but I doubt that's possible).

```
/data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:zombie,limit=1] ??? set value 1
```

Neither the wiki, nor anywhere else for that matter, goes into any detail whatsoever as to what I'm supposed to put there. I have tried a wide variety of variations on the `{HandDropChances:[0.0f,0.0f]}` and it either comes back saying nothing has changed, or "Modified enttiy data of Zombie", without actually changing anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would someone give a thorough explanation of 1.14 Minecraft's /data modify?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351488/would-someone-give-a-thorough-explanation-of-1-14-minecrafts-data-modify)

Comment: not a duplicate. the link deals with a block while this deals with an entity, which have very different data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the `???` with a simple "path" of the value you want to change. For example to change the entire `HandDropChances` value to `[1f, 1f]` (which will guarantee drops from both hands), simply use

`/data modify entity <entity> HandDropChances set value [1f, 1f]`

The full path of the value we change is `HandDropChances` as it's stored directly in the root object. To change a value that's stored in another object use dots as separators between parents and children elements (e.g the path of `memories` object in the `Brain` object will be `Brain.memories`).
If you want to set the chances of the drops from the first hand only, you will need to add the array index of the `HandDropChances` array in your path like this:

`/data modify entity <entity> HandDropChances[0] set value 1f`

Note that the first element of the array is `0` and not `1`.

`/data merge` is also a decent alternative for the `modify` command. It lets you simply merge a JSON element with the entity's JSON data. For example the following command will be an equivalent for the first `modify` command I suggested:

`/data merge entity <entity> {HandDropChances: [1f, 1f]}`

That will add the `HandDropChances` element if it's not present in the entity and will replace it otherwise.

Comment: i'm saving this in a text file, because it's too useful to trust to my memory.

Comment: Thanks <3
Did my best to explain it as well as I can.